# A Problem related to the Cauchy Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The following problem is from the book, "Introduction to Probability" by
Hoel, Port and Stone. My answer does not match the back of the book. What did I do wrong?
Thanks,
Bob
Problem:
Let $X$ have a Cauchy density. Find the upper quartile for $X$.
Answer:
Recall the density function for the Cauchy distribution is:
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac{1}{x^2+1} \\
\end{align*}
Let $a$ be the number we seek.
\begin{align*}
F(x) &= \tan^{-1}{x} \\
\int_{-\infty}^{a}  \frac{1}{x^2+1} \,\, dx &= \frac{3}{4} \\
\tan^{-1} \Big|_{-\infty}^{a} &= \frac{3}{4} \\
\tan^{-1}(a) - \frac{-\pi}{2} &= \frac{3}{4} \\
\tan^{-1}(a) + \frac{\pi}{2} &= \frac{3}{4} \\
\tan^{-1}(a) &= \frac{3}{4} - \frac{\pi}{2} \\
\end{align*}
The books's answer is $1$. What did I do wrong?

I ran the following command in R: pcauchy(1) . R returned 0.75 therefore,
I believe the book is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the factor $\frac{1}{\pi}$ in the probability density function. Correct density function is
$$
f(x) =\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}
$$ so that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx =1$. Your problem is to find $a$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^a \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\arctan a+\frac{\pi}{2}}{\pi}=\frac{3}{4}
$$ or equivalently
$$
\arctan a=\frac{\pi}{4}.
$$ This gives $a=\tan \frac{\pi}{4}=1$.